# Pestaña inesperada al momento de guardar con CKEditor 4

Tags: php, laravel, ckeditor

Hace unas semanas que estoy trabajando en un proyecto con laravel, al cual le implemente CKEditor4 para que reemplazara a los textarea en el sistema, todo bien, hasta dar en guardar en el icono de la barra de tareas el cual da como resultado una nueva pestaña en blanco con un trozo de código.Destaco que la acción si se realiza (si guarda), pero no logro entender porque emerge esta nueva pestaña, ya que es molesta.

He intentado quitar el botón 'guardar' de la barra de tareas de CKEditor y que se guarden los cambios solo oprimiendo 'siguiente'(como lo hacia antes de implementar CKEditor), pero éste ya no hace esa función.

Ésta es la pestaña que me surge cuando doy guardar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo cual creo que esta relacionado con este trozo de código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Bueno amigos espero que sepan entender mi problema y me puedan ayudar, gracias.

Comment: Lo más seguro es que en tu vista tengas algo así `<a href="#" target="_blank">`

Comment: Debes incluir el codigo que usas para la implementacion del boton "siguiente". Debe ser distinto a la implementacion de guardar del editor.